# Playing Youtubes with UIWebView ios6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, youtube

Struggling to play youtube videos with UIWebView.  I'm actually doing it in a UIWebView subclass, but I have the same problem without the subclass.

I've tried several different methods found on stackoverflow, and all have provided identical results.  The video still startup screen for the video displays in the window, but when I press the play button I get messages as follows:

===========

[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)

setting movie path: http://r13---sn-q4f7dnsz.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?expire=1371905026&newshard=yes&mt=1371882265&ip=206.255.xx.xxx&itag=18&ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&mv=m&sver=3&ms=au&ipbits=8&upn=CUdV_ZV6gvs&fexp=(several lines of useless garbage here)

[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay

[MPCloudAssetDownloadController] Prioritization requested for media item ID: 0

============

And then it stops.  However, if I hit continue in the debugger maybe 10-15 times, the video will play to completion.

The code I'm [currently] using is:

```
NSString *html = @"<iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/hD6BCyT206w\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";


[self loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

I've been stuck on this all day, so I'm hoping someone will have seen it before and have some idea for me.  TIA

Regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that by disabling all breakpoints in the project this would run to completion with incident.

Comment: yeah that worked..thanks a lot.. i wasted lot of hours figuring out the issue. do u know the reason...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I never found out why it was.  Although, IIRC, I later added back breakpoints without a problem.  Just no idea, really.